# Having period job to remove temporary files

Tags: terminal, bash, launchd

I've defined a periodic plist which runs a bash script. The plist is placed in the local library and script is also place in `/usr/local/bin`. It successfully run the script on the defined period but it errored about not having enough permission to run the find command. Find command is used in the script and running script without plist works as expected.

> `/usr/local/bin/cleanup.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

stable_folders=(
    "$HOME/Downloads"
    "$HOME/Downloads/Telegram Desktop"
    "$HOME/Downloads/samba"
    "$HOME/Downloads/xandikos"
    "$HOME/Downloads/copyparty"
    "$HOME/Downloads/swagger"
    "$HOME/Downloads/movies"
)

for folder in "${stable_folders[@]}"; do
    mkdir -p "$folder" || true
done

while read -r folder; do
    # shellcheck disable=2076
    if [[ ! " ${stable_folders[*]} " =~ " ${folder} " ]]; then
        echo "removing $folder..."
        rm -rf "$folder"
    fi
done < <(find "$HOME/Downloads" -maxdepth 1 -mtime +12h)

while read -r file; do
    echo "removing $file..."
    # shellcheck disable=2076
    rm -rf "$file"
done < <(find "$HOME/Downloads/Telegram Desktop" -mindepth 1 -mtime +15m)
```

> `~/Library/LaunchAgents/me.1995parham.cleanup.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>me.1995parham.cleanup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/cleanup.sh</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>60</integer>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/opt/homebrew/var/log/cleanup.log</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/opt/homebrew/var/log/cleanup.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and these are the errors:

```
find: /Users/parham/Downloads: Operation not permitted
removing /Users/parham/Downloads...
rm: /Users/parham/Downloads: Operation not permitted
find: /Users/parham/Downloads/Telegram Desktop: Operation not permitted
find: /Users/parham/Downloads: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: What username is the script running under, and what are the permissions for `/Users/parham/Downloads`?

Comment: You don't want it to remove ~/Downloads anyway, so you should fix that. TCC protection is biting you re `find` trying to search inside $HOME.  I found https://www.rainforestqa.com/blog/macos-tcc-db-deep-dive very informative.

Comment: Yes, I've added the Downloads folder into the exception list.

Comment: I put the plist under the Home library, so I think it runs using `parham` and `parham` has read-write access for Downloads folder.

Comment: UNIX permissions are not your issue.  TCC is your issue.  I assume you need to grant permissions to `find`, at a minimum.  Probably `bash` too.